# how to declare and use right an std::array in C++

Tags: c++, function, declaration

I have this two-dimensional array : **`array <array <int , 4> , 4> myarray`**

How do I declare it right in a program?

```
//I first include
  #include <array>
```

then I initialize it

```
        array<array<int,4>,4> myarray = {{
                                           {1, 2, 3, 4},
                                           {5, 6, 0, 8},
                                           {9, 10, 11, 12},
                                           {13, 14, 15, 7}
                                        }};
```

I declare my functions:

```
        void func1(array<array<int,4>,4> );
        void func2();
        void func3(int&, int&, array<array<int,4>,4>);
        void func4(array<array<int,4>,4>);
        void func5(array<array<int,4>,4>);
        void func6(array<array<int,4>,4>);
```

write a main function:

```
    int main() {
                     func1(myarray);                                
                     func2();  
                     func3(myarray);  
                     func4(myarray);    
                     func5(myarray);   
                     func6(myarray);   
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Then I write the functions

```
    void func1(array<array<int,4>,4> myarray)
        {//something 
        }

    void func2();
        {//something 
        }

    void func3(int&, int&, array<array<int,4>,4> myarray);
        {//something 
        }

    void func4(array<array<int,4>,4> myarray);
        {//something 
        }

    void func5(array<array<int,4>,4> myarray);
        {//something 
        }

    void func6(array<array<int,4>,4> myarray);
        {//something 
        }
```

Am I somewhere wrong ?

The point is, that the initialized array :    `{1, 2, 3, 4},  {5, 6, 0, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12},   {13, 14, 15, 7}` will be input in the first func . The output of the first func will be a different 4x4 array,for example `{15, 14, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {2, 1, 4, 13}`. This different array will be put as input in the second.The output of this func will be something different etc,etc....

The **problem** that I have is that the output of most functions is the initialized array.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: None of those functions return anything, or modify `myarray`, since they are all given their own copy.  Did you mean to pass by reference?  `&myarray`?

Comment: Why do you focus on asking about the *declaration* of the array? If there were a problem with the declaration, the compiler would have told you, and you wouldn't have gotten to the point of running your program at all. Please always describe the *symptoms* of a problem, not your *diagnosis*. The symptom, in this case, is that you apply functions to your variable, and yet its value doesn't change. Make *that* the primary topic of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The process goes like this. You initialize your array:

```
array<array<int,4>,4> myarray = {{
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
  {5, 6, 0, 8},

          {9, 10, 11, 12},
       {13, 14, 15, 7}
       }};
```

Then, in `main`, you call `func1`. The implementation of `funct1` is:

```
void func1(array<array<int,4>,4> myarray)
        {//something 
        }
```

Since you declared `func1` as `void` that means that it does not return a value. 
`array<array<int,4>,4> myarray` is type of the argument of function `func1`. When you call function `func1` from `main`, the variable you pass from `main` function **will be copied** into the `myarray` variable of `func1` (this is called pass by value), and logically, it is totally new array. If you want to change values of your function arguments you can use references or pointers. If so, implementation of your function will be:

```
void func1(array<array<int,4>,4> &myarray)
            {//something 
            }
```

The `&` symbol means that `myarray` is reference of the variable you passed to the function. So if, in function `func1`, you modify values of `myarray`, then array in your `main` function will be also modifed (because you modified the values in function `func1`).